# Fetch data keep not display on browser using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, fetch

I am creating a simple fetching data using ReactJS and MySql as my database. For connection between front end and the back, I am using express, everything is okay with array data appear in console.log but not in html page.

I am added another package "node-fetch" but also not working.

Here is my code on App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../src/components/Navbar';
import './App.css';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tbl_barang: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(tbl_barang => this.setState({data: tbl_barang}, () => console.log('Customers fetched...', tbl_barang)));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Navbar />
        <h1>Daftar Barang</h1>
        <ul>
        {this.state.tbl_barang.map(tbl_barang =>
          <li key={tbl_barang.id}>
            {tbl_barang.tipe_barang}
            {tbl_barang.product_name}
          </li>
        )}
        </ul>

        <button> Click disini </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and here is the code to get the data from MySQL

```
const path = require ('path');
const mysql = require ('mysql');

module.exports = function (app, connection) {
    //if no matching path, back to index.html
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        connection.query('SELECT id, tipe_barang, product_name FROM tbl_barang', function (err, data){
            (err)? res.send(err):res.json ({data});
        })
    })
}
```

I expected the array data display on the html page

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re setting `state.data` instead of `state.tbl_barang`. To fix this, change your `componentDidMount()` body:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(tbl_barang => this.setState({tbl_barang: tbl_barang.data}, () => console.log('Customers fetched...', tbl_barang)));
}
```

You could also update your component to use the `state.data` property instead, this depends on what name you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for help...
I tried your suggestion, but I got this error
```
MainProduct.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: this.state.tbl_barang.map is not a function
```

Comment: @Shinichi1988 Sorry, didn't look at your mysql API. The data returned from your fetch request is parsed JSON. The array should be in `tbl_barang.data`. If it's not, can you supply a pastebin of your `console.log`?

Comment: ```
{data: Array(3)}
data: Array(3)
0: {id: 1, tipe_barang: "Laptop", product_name: "HP", image: {…}}
1: {id: 2, tipe_barang: "PC/Komputer", product_name: "HP", image: {…}}
2: {id: 3, tipe_barang: "Printer", product_name: "HP", image: {…}}
```
here is my console.log @YSbakker

Comment: @Shinichi1988 yes, so the array seems to be in `tbl_barang.data`. Use this: `this.setState({tbl_barang: tbl_barang.data}` and let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried and still not working @YSbakker ...
I am using chrome ,,, is there a problem with the browser?

Comment: This isn’t a problem with your browser. You have to make sure that you’re actually putting an array in `state.tbl_barang`. Try using `console.log(state.tbl_barang)` in your component to see what it contains.

Comment: using console.log(this.state.tbl_barang) not working, it make the array not appear

Comment: What is the output you’re seeing? If it’s `undefined`, you’re still not setting the state correctly. Can you put the code you have right now on a JSFiddle so I can check it out?

Comment: yes, it's undefined now
the code right now :

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(tbl_barang => this.setState({data: tbl_barang.data}, () => console.log(this.state.tbl_barang)));
    }

Comment: Replace `this.setState({data: tbl_barang.data})` with `this.setState({tbl_barang: tbl_barang.data})`

Comment: I got ths error:
react-dom.development.js:13813 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, tipe_barang, product_name, image}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Comment: in render , I use this, 
 render() {
        return (
        <div className='MainProductPage'>
            <h2>Main Products Available</h2>
            <ul>
            {this.state.tbl_barang.map(tbl_barang =>
            <li key={tbl_barang.id}>
                {tbl_barang.tipe_barang}
                {tbl_barang.product_name}
                {tbl_barang.image}
            </li>
            )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
  }

Comment: At this point, it’s very difficult for me to reproduce and therefore troubleshoot. You’ll have to do some debugging yourself, I’d suggest looking at the data in `state.tbl_barang`, it looks like this isn’t formatted correctly

Comment: hi  @YSbakker, I change my state to this, and got the problem that tbl_barang is property undefined.
 .then(tbl_barang => this.setState({tbl_barang: tbl_barang.tbl_barang, isLoading: false}, () => console.log('Main Product available are ... ', this.state.tbl_barang)))

Comment: Look, the `.then()` of your fetch request receives a callback function where the first parameter is the entire fetch response. Let’s say we’ll call this parameter `data` instead of `tbl_barang`. At that moment the `data` binding contains the entire JSON response object, so it’s up to you to get the correct data out of that. From your earlier comments, it looks like the `data.data` property contains the array of database records. You have to find out what your data structure is by doing some debugging, and I can’t help you with that unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you would want to have two components, App and for the data the map function should point to an Item component, and you can pass the props down to the child.

So in your render change to...

```
  render() {
   return (
   <div className='App'>
    <Navbar />
    <h1>Daftar Barang</h1>
    {this.state.tbl_barang.map(tbl_barang =>
      <TableItem key={tbl_barang.id} tbl_barang={tbl_barang} />
    }
    )}
```

Then make a TableItem component, I usually make a separate file for this component.

```
const TableItem = ({ tbl_barang }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {tbl_barang.tipe_barang}
            {tbl_barang.product_name}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TableItem;
```

Comment: I separate the code above to two components, but the problem still the same.

Comment: While I agree that making separate components for the List & ListItem makes more sense, this is not the problem. The problem is that the wrong part of `state` is being updated, see my answer.

Comment: @YSbakker I tried your suggestion, but I got another error :
Uncaught TypeError: this.state.tbl_barang.map is not a function